# Cannot parse through a file with latin-1 encoding

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to parse a large file of tweets from the Stanford Sentiment Database (see here: http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students/), with the following being my code:

```
def init_process(fin, fout):
    outfile = open(fout, 'a')
    with open(fin, buffering=200000, encoding='latin-1') as f:
        try:
            for line in f:
                line = line.replace('"', '')
                initial_polarity = line.split(',')[0]
                if initial_polarity == '0':
                    initial_polarity = [1, 0]
                elif initial_polarity == '4':
                    initial_polarity = [0, 1]

                tweet = line.split(',')[-1]
                outline = str(initial_polarity) + ':::' + tweet
                outfile.write(outline)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    outfile.close()

init_process('training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv','train_set.csv')
```

I've run into this following issue:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 12-14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

which doesn't make sense since I'm opening the file with a latin-1 encoding. How do I stop this error and successfully parse through the file?

Comment: CSV being textual, I would pre-process off-line and transform the entire file using encoding converters (e.g. [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)), probably to [UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/). That would go quickly. The files are not that big. Your time is more valuable than computer time. Read also http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: Can you show the full traceback and an input file that produces this error?

Comment: @Åsmund The link I provided has a download link of a zip file which, when unzipped, yields a folder with two csv files, one of which is the input file. Furthermore, that was the entirety of the traceback error that was given.

Comment: Thank you @BasileStarynkevitch for the resource, seems enlightening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably the outfile encoding that's still ASCII. You should open it with the proper encoding, too (doesn't have to be latin-1, probably utf-8 is more appropriate depending on your environment).

Per comment from Åsmund: the file encoding is locale-specific, you should probably consider changing your locale to something that can handle non-ASCII text.

Comment: Can add that this is locale-dependent. If running the script in an UTF-8 locale, the error doesn't occur.

Comment: Yes that is plausible, didn't think of this as I'm normally working in an utf-8 locale.